# How do I cancel an EXIT sigspec?

Tags: bash

Consider:

```
finalize() {
    echo finalizing...
}

trap finalize EXIT

bla() {
    exit 1
}

bla

#I was expecting for the next line to be executed after finalize()
echo "I want to go on"
```

I have the `finalize()` function to cleanup after an error condition but I don't want the shell to actually exit. Is there a way to prevent it from exiting after `finalize()` finishes?

Comment: What do you want it to do instead of exiting?

Comment: @oguzismail I want the whole call stack that caused the exception to be unwound(I understand that is actually what happens with an exit) and then the shell to proceed normally, i.e. execute/await the next command.

Comment: *stack*? *exception*? This is a shell scripting language, you're expecting too much from it. There might be workarounds though, but we can't say that without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: @oguzismail See the code now. I want the final `echo` command to be executed after `finalize()`

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to me